# Check if a.txt file exists or not on a remote webserver

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to check if .txt file is exists or not from web url. This is my code:

```
static public bool URLExists(string url)
{
    bool result = false;

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Timeout = 1200; // miliseconds
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";

    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        result = true;
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        //(url + " doesn't exist: " + webException.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If i enter "http://www.example.com/demo.txt" is not a valid file path and website showing 404 error page then this code return `true`. How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this url "http://www.example.com/URLExists?url=demo.txt"

Comment: Can you describe your actual problem better? You want it to show a 404? or just return false? You need to re-structure your question.

Comment: Why do you believe a 404 will result in a WebException? You have to check the `response.StatusCode` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: #AusssieJoe I want to show false,

Comment: In your catch statement, return false then?

Comment: @AussieJoe - he doesnt want to check if a file exists on his machine - he wants to check if a file exists on a webserver hence the URL he is trying to pass into his method

Comment: @AussieJoe - his result boolean is initialized with false so it will return false on exception, but as I said a 404 webrequest will NOT fire an exception therefor his method returns true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `StatusCode` property of the `HttpWebResponse` object.

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
  result = false;
}
else
{
  result = true;
}
```

Look through the [list of possible status codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) to see which ones you want to interpret as the file not existing.

Comment: For example if i try "http://www.youdial.in/robots2.txt" is not a valid file path, and you will see a custom made 404 error page. Your code will return TRUE (file found) but i want to show file not found. Sorry for my bad English, i'm a non English person.

Comment: The site youdial.in is incorrectly configured and returns status code 200 when displaying the 404 error page.

Comment: Problem was in the website, your code was working well. Thanks!